# Need to import a key and value from the file in same directory

Tags: python, dictionary

path/

```
  file_name.py
  main.py
```

file_name.py contains below code only

```
{ 'app_name':'NTorq'}
```

and nothing else

now how do i access **app_name** in my **main.py** file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python file you described only contains data, so there is no need to be a python file.

Coincidentally the JSON file format has a similar syntax for dictionaries and lists as Python. That means that

```
{"app_name":"ntorq"}
```

is valid by the rules of both format.

I suggest you rename it to name_file.json just to be clear about the purpose of the file.

After read it with the [json](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html) module.

```
import json
name = json.load(open('name_file.json'))['app_name']
```

Comment: How do i import as it doesn't have class

Comment: I meant Do i need to  import that file if yes how do i import that json file

Comment: I did renamed it to .json file. But my only question is , just like we import python files, don't we need to import this json file

Comment: Should i need to add this in my main.py file

`import file_name`

Comment: You don't need to import it. The open() function will read the contents of the file, and the load will interpret it.

Comment: One last question, if the json file in different folder, how do i load it

Comment: Then use the absolute path to the file. e.g. _C:\myprogram\data\name.json_. Look up the Python reference for all possibilities of `open()`

Answer (score 0):

If `file_name.py` contains only `{ 'app_name':'NTorq'}`, That's JSON file, not a python file.
And if you want to read the `app_name.py` and convert it to JSON, you should follow Handras' answer.

Or you can make your data in `file_name.py` to a variable.
For example,

file_name.py

```
foo = {'app_name':'NTorq'}
```

And then import it.

main.py

```
from file_name import foo
print(foo["app_name"])
```

output

```
NTorq
```